# OS for Orange Pi zero plus

Tags: security, wifi

I bought an orange pi zero plus and want to make a wifi access point that passes all traffic of the connected devices through tor.

Simply I wanted a dev board that has gigabit ethernet and wifi for access point, and is as cheap as possible.

I want to create a secure pathway through tor. So I installed Tails(not specifically but for the sake of its features) on my sd card and tried to turn my Pi on, but nothing, not even led's glow. I am sure that power adapter is working fine and same is ethernet cable.

Does Tails has to do with any of this?
I assumed that most of lightweight distros can run pretty fine on new dev boards. Should I install armbian instead of tails? if yes, then why won't tails work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some Orange Pi components are in the mainline kernel and some are not. To have a full running Linux OS, you should use [armbian](https://www.armbian.com/orange-pi-zero-plus/).
If you want to use another distro than Debian/Ubuntu, you need to use [Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/) in order to build your own image. There is a [recipe for the Allwinner](https://gitlab.com/dimtass/meta-allwinner-hx) used in the Orange Pi Zero.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure Tails supports the Orange Pi?

The System requirements page implies it only supports x86_64 based hardware:

https://tails.boum.org/doc/about/requirements/index.en.html

Comment: Orange Pi is 64-bit architecture built. Have a look here:
http://www.orangepi.org/OrangePiZeroPlus

Comment: The orange pi uses a 64bit Arm processor, not a x86_64 processor

Comment: Oh so arm doesn't work as x86? I might have been wrong about this. So tails cannot run here.

Comment: No, Arm and x86/x86_64 are totally different CPU architectures, you can not interchange them.